# Hiding the parent after clicking a specific element : Jquery troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hide, addclass

We are on the last step of a project and we can't get rid of this problem.

Basically, the page we are working on is a form to create chapters within a video. For each chapter created, a small "card" is created after validation. We want to enable users to supress the chapters by clicking on a X Font-Awesome icon displayed within each chapter card.

The idea : after clicking the X, the card disappears via hide() / get a new class .displayNone and fade out.

So we have this HTML structure for the "cards" :

```
            <div class="ch">
                <p>
                    <i class="fa fa-times fa-fw chap"></i> Chap. '.$row->num.'
                        <ul>
                            <li id="li" value="'.$row->ID_sequence.'">Titre : '.$row->title.'</li>
                            <li>D&eacute;but : '.$row->tcStart.'s</li>
                            <li>Fin : '.$row->tcEnd.'s</li>
                        </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
```

And we tried this for the Jquery

```
$(".chap").click(function () {
            var VignParent = $( this ).parents('.ch');
            VignParent.addClass('displayNone');
            VignParent.fadeOut( 100 );
           });
```

And also this

```
$("i").click(function () {
        $( ".ch" ).hide( "slow");
      });
```

None of these works, so I am wondering some help on Internet. We tried a lot of things after searching here, of course, and this JS are the last attempts ...
Thanks in advance for helping us out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If new cards are created dynamically (with js/ajax) then there are no listeners attached to them. Try this code

```
$(document).on('click', '.chap', function () {
   $( this ).parents('.ch')
            .addClass('displayNone')
            .fadeOut( 100 );
});
```

ps: and you probably have empty tag `<i class="fa fa-times fa-fw chap"></i>`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. Using the code you provided did not directly, but by inserting into the function made for cleaning the database, it performed smoothly. That is my first request on stackoverflow ... first answer, and it's done ! Thanks again